# multiple resultsets in stored procedures

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that is a class in my project.  I gain the data returned by following:

```
EMTS.SPs.PrcEMTSDataLookup(so).GetDataSet().Tables[0].Copy()
```

This is placed in a `dataset`.  The issue is the stored procedure has several selects and each select needs to be placed in a separate grid.

I have tried `IDataReader` and `IDataAdapter` but have not had any luck pulling data from the stored procedure object.  I have research microsoft for information on `IDataAdapter` and the example they give uses `SqlDataAdapter` which is not necessary for me since the stored procedure is an object in the project.

So how do I get the different result sets in the `sp` and put them in separate grids?

Comment: SqlDataReader.NextResult should bring you to the next resultset. http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx

Comment: then why when following code is used my grids return empty  long so = 0;
            so = Convert.ToInt32(txtSoForLookup.Text);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(EMTS.SPs.PrcEMTSDataLookup(so).GetDataSet().Tables[0].Copy());
            IDataReader dsDataReader = ds.Tables[0].CreateDataReader();
            ugLookUpResults.DataSource = dsDataReader.NextResult();
            ugLookUpResults1.DataSource = dsDataReader.NextResult();
            ugLookUpResults2.DataSource = dsDataReader.NextResult();

Comment: You should create the datareader directly from the sqlcommand. With this code you already loaded only the first resultset. See this post for usage: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311274

Comment: ok so there is not away to parse ds.tables[0] to get the individual resultsets without useing SQLDataReader

Comment: yes, you can try this: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1564/how-to-work-with-multiple-results-set-using-dataset

Comment: Your DataSet will have a Table for each select. The index is based on the order of the select.

Comment: I do not need to make a connection to my database with a connection string.  The object EMTS.SPs.PrcEMTSDataLookup(so).GetDataSet().Tables[0].Copy() does that.  So I need to know how to parse this object to get the different result sets.  no SQLDataAdapter, no SQlDataReader is needed.

Comment: As Mufaka said you will have a resultset in each table. In your code you're using only the first table in the dataset. Try to look into Tables[1] and you should find the second resultset

Comment: Thanks for all of your responses. A little tweaking to code on my side and we will be good to go.